# How does a compass behave on magnetic south

Tags: magnetic-fields

At school, we have been going through magnetism. I was thinking about compasses and how they worked,  but this question stumped me:

“Imagine you are standing on the magnetic South Pole. Now, you use a compass. How will the compas behave?”

My hypothesis is that the North Pole of the compass will be facing the South Pole of Earth, and vice versa. I think this may be true because of magnetic attraction between opposites. However, some sources of which I read state that the compass gets disoriented.

I do not know if my hypothesis is right, the articles I read is right or if both are wrong.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Imagine this, if I asked you to point north and you are standing exactly on the south pole....which way do you point?

Comment: the answer here may help you understand how a compass aligns itself to the field lines of a magnet.  North was defined as a geographic direction of the earth, and it became common to call the pole of the compass pointing to geographic north , north. Actually it has the opposite field lines as you surmise, https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/606484/is-earths-north-pole-actualy-a-south-pole .see this also https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-26763,00.html

Comment: While it is common to refer to a compass as having a "north pole", a better term is that it has a "north-seeking pole".   The north magnetic pole of the earth and the "north pole" of a compass have opposite polarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are standing at the magnetic south pole and holding a magnetic compass in the usual 'horizontal' plane, then no direction of the needle points to north. The needle is orthogonal to the 'north' direction, all directions are to outer space, and the needle will behave erratically.

If you want to find the direction of the north pole, hold the compass in a vertical plane.

But you don't need a compass to do that – just point to your feet: that's the direction of the north pole.

---

In answer to OP's comment.

To put it another way, there are "lines of flux" between the magnetic poles, to which the compass needle normally aligns. When *on* the pole, which of those do you think the needle should align with?

Comment: Hi @Weather Vane! I was wondering what you mean by “all directions go to outer space”. Aren’t magnetic fields curved, like how they normally illustrate in photos?

Comment: They are, but north isn't in *any* direction the needle is pointing. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you hold compass in standard position it's magnetic field lines can't align with Earth magnetic field lines because they are perpendicular to each other. This position is unstable, because $N$ of compass will be attracted downwards, and $S$ of compass will be pushed upwards, so compass arrow will be bent down.
Like that :
[image]

You can get a similar situation if you hold a compass in your room vertically at "usual Longitude, Latitude" coordinates (not at poles). But this situation will be a bit different, because this time arrow can't balance normally due to applied weight, which will make arrow "stuck" on the needle.